# Converting 1 meter to decimal degrees using FME

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form

I am using FME's Tester to select objects that are bigger than 1 meter.

My data are in EPSG:4326.

How much is 1 meter in decimal degrees?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although I like Alex's answer - it's better to reproject than to simply convert decimal degrees to metres with a fixed multiplier - I never really like having to reproject data back and forth if not necessary. I figure you're bound to lose some degree of accuracy/precision.

What I would try is the **ReprojectLengthCalculator** transformer. With that you could measure the length in decimal degrees and reproject that attribute value. You wouldn't need to reproject the feature to metres and back again.

[image]

The drawback here is that I think it will only really work with 2-point lines and - for some reason - you'll have to calculate the angle of that line as part of the input.

If you do reproject as Alex suggests, then I would encourage you to do that as a separate stream, and merge the resulting distance back onto the original data. That way you retain a good (un-reprojected) copy of the geometry.

I also suggest reprojecting to a dynamic coordinate system; `_AZMED_` for measuring distances, and `_AZMEA_` for measuring areas. Each feature effectively gets converted to its own equal-distance (equal-area) coordinate system, giving the best results.

I think it would look something like this:

[image]

You *could* put the Tester after the FeatureMerger, but I think this configuration is more efficient. The FeatureMerger will need a unique ID on the features to work.

Answer (score 3):

I can propose you to do next steps in order to get results with appropriate accuracy:

1. [Reproject](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FMETransformers.htm#transformers/reprojector.htm) your data into some projected CS with metric units.
2. [Calculate length](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FMETransformers.htm#transformers/lengthcalculator.htm) and use [Tester](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FMETransformers.htm#transformers/tester.htm) transformer.
3. [Reproject](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FMETransformers.htm#transformers/reprojector.htm) your data back into source CS (EPSG:4326).

This part of the model should look like:

[image: model example]

It is also possible to use GeometryExtractor and GeometryReplacer transformers. In this case we will not modify geometry of the feature at all and we can get rid of `Reprojector_2`:

[image: model example 2]