# Converting 1 meter to degrees at specific location using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

Given a point in EPSG:4326 I need to know how many degrees (approx) 1 meter is at this location using PostGIS.  Feels like http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html is useful here but I cannot figure it out.

Another way to phrase this question is: What is one point (X) here that would give me 1 meter back when running the following query?

```
  ST_Distance(
   'SRID=4326;POINT(Input point)'::geography,
   'SRID=4326;POINT(X)'::geography) AS geography_distance
   ;
```

I would happily accept a point in any direction.

Here is the same question but using "FME's Tester"
[Converting 1 meter to decimal degrees using FME](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26335/how-much-is-1-meter-in-decimal-degrees)

Comment: This is going to depend on direction. 1 metre N-S next to the pole is a very different number of degrees to 1 metre E-W (which could be 360 degrees if you are standing next to the pole!)

Comment: True, I would be OK with any direction.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I mocked up [a *PL/pgSQL* function](https://gist.github.com/geozelot/5cf8425160b98394d0f9ba50ce76917e) of pieces of code I use to avoid costly projections and rule-of-three calculations. Takes into account a given angular direction of distance and the variance in its degree representation, or defaults to longitudinal direction. Assumes Earth is a sphere.

Comment: @geozelot that is brilliant!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute the following query, you can modify coordinates in CTE `start_coords` :

```sql
WITH start_coords AS (SELECT 5 AS long, 40 AS lat),
start_point AS (SELECT *, ST_MakePoint(long, lat)::geography AS geog FROM start_coords)

SELECT
    sp.lat,
    sp.long,
    ST_Distance(
        sp.geog,
        ST_MakePoint(sp.long, sp.lat + 1)::geography
    ) AS one_deg_lat_north,  -- in meters
    1 / ST_Distance(
        sp.geog,
        ST_MakePoint(sp.long, sp.lat + 1)::geography
    ) AS one_meter_lat_north,  -- in degrees
    ST_Distance(
        sp.geog,
        ST_MakePoint(sp.long, sp.lat - 1)::geography
    ) AS one_deg_lat_south,  -- in meters
    1 / ST_Distance(
        sp.geog,
        ST_MakePoint(sp.long, sp.lat - 1)::geography
    ) AS one_meter_lat_south,  -- in degrees
    ST_Distance(
        sp.geog,
        ST_MakePoint(sp.long + 1, sp.lat)::geography
    ) AS one_deg_long_east,  -- in meters
    1 / ST_Distance(
        sp.geog,
        ST_MakePoint(sp.long + 1, sp.lat)::geography
    ) AS one_meter_long_east,  -- in degrees
    ST_Distance(
        sp.geog,
        ST_MakePoint(sp.long - 1, sp.lat)::geography
    ) AS one_deg_long_west,  -- in meters
    1 / ST_Distance(
        sp.geog,
        ST_MakePoint(sp.long - 1, sp.lat)::geography
    ) AS one_meter_long_west  -- in degrees
FROM start_point sp
;
```

Comment: ST_MakePoint(sp.long, sp.lat + 1)::geography <-- This is not corresponding to 1 meter right? I do not think this solution is correct

Comment: Look at the entire code, the part you mention is to compute, from the coordinates of the original point, a new geography point with an additionnal degree for the latitude. Then it compute the distance between the original point and this new point to get the number of meters for 1 degree, so `1 degree / number of meters` gives you the number of degrees for 1 meter, see the SQL comments for the unit.

Comment: Thats smart. Why did I not think of this